# What is the best way to consume data from a pipe?

Tags: c, unix, pipe

I'm interested in the more portable yet fastest way to consume data from a pipe.

For example, in linux the fastest way I can think of is the following:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
/* ... */
int fd;
int pipefd[2];

pipe(pipefd);

/* ... */
fd = open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);
splice(pipefd[0], NULL, fd, NULL, INT_MAX, SPLICE_F_MOVE);
```

... but it's not portable.

**UPDATE 1:**

What if I close the entire pipe and create one each time I need it?

```
/*consume*/
close(pipefd[0]);
close(pipefd[1]);
```

would it be faster than using other methods, i.e. read()/write()?

Comment: `pipe` is POSIX conforming, so it is portable on POSIX-compliant systems. `splice` is Linux only system call, though.

Comment: Why do you want to consume data from a pipe? [What is your real problem?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: @thkala I just want to consume data from a pipe. I'm implementing a server, **for example**, suppose there is an incoming connection, the server handles the request and prepare all the necesary things to make a response back to the client, but something has happened; the client closed the connection. In this point the server can't make a response back to the client, now the server needs to recover from this in order to handle other requests.

now, what would you do with the data inside pipefd[0] previously filled by the server? IMO, either you cosume the data or close the pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that this operation is performance critical to your program? If not, just use the simplest thing that works, probably something along the lines`cat the_pipe > /dev/null` or its equivalent in C, a loop read(2)ing a block of data (say 4KiB, or perhaps get an "optimal" size, on current Linux the maximal data in a pipe is 64KiB; take a look at pipe(7)).
Perhaps it is easier to shut up the producer of the data instead of getting it only to throw it away? In performance terms, that just can't be beat...

Comment: Indeed this is not the application's bottleneck. The best way is to use a larger buffer as you said. Although it seems like libevent provide a portable zero-copy interface that uses low level primitives provided by the host operative system. Seems to me, libevent is very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `read` function.
Refer to the man pages here - http://linux.die.net/man/3/read